# Replace or remove data in column based on another column value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I replace or remove data from a column that is found in another column?

I cannot undo or prevent the way the data is being inserted, I must instead be able to determine the `Address` by removing all of the data found in the `Place` column.

The pre-calculated data populates this column as:

```
[Address] = '123 Main Street" + ': @McDonalds'
```

For Example:

```
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+
| ID |    Place    |           Address           |
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | :@McDonalds | 123 Main Street: @McDonalds |
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+
```

I'd like the content of `[Address]` to be only:

> 123 Main Street

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option:
Return the left part of a character string after finding the index of the ":" character.

```
UPDATE tbl
    SET
        [Address] = LEFT([Address], CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(':', [Address]) = 0 THEN
                      LEN([Address]) ELSE CHARINDEX(':', [Address]) - 1 END)
```

Another option:

```
UPDATE tbl
    SET
        [Address] = REPLACE([Address], [Place], '')
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/4916)

Comment: So you posted a question and two ways to do this in less than a minute. Do you actually need help here?

Comment: Originally I had, and started asking the question, but I couldn't find an answer specific to my situation. So I decided to just use the feature (– share your knowledge, Q&A-style) and post an answer to help others, once I figured it out.